# file_get_contents invalidates rss xml file

Tags: php, xml, rss, file-get-contents

I have a script which pulls an outputted RSS feed with file_get_contents periodically, and then writes a static xml file of it with file_put_contents.

The original file contains this header

```
<channel>
    <title>Title</title>
    <description>Desc</description>
    <link>http://www.example.hu</link>
    <lastBuildDate>Tue, 08 Aug 2017 10:20:06 +0200</lastBuildDate>
    <image>
        <url>http://www.example.hu/ef_rss_bg.jpg</url>
        <title>Image title</title>
        <link>http://www.example.hu</link>
    </image>
    <!-- items -->
</channel>
```

The script is like this:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://dynamic_rss_file');
file_put_contents('static.xml',trim($xml));
```

Somehow the static xml file ends up with the  tag replaced with

```
<img>
     <url>http://www.example.hu/ef_rss_bg.jpg</url>
     <title>Image title</title>
     <link>http://www.example.hu</link>
</image>
```

Comment: _SIlly Suggestion:_ Try removing the `trim()` XML should be UTF-8 and I dont think `trim()` is UTF-8 aware

Comment: It could be that that is true, but it still can't replace an <image> with <img>

Comment: Absolutely correct. So I would look else where. Obviously either the incoming XML is wrong, or something else is messing with the file after you write it

Comment: Ok, I wrote a php script which replaces the incorrect <img> tag in the static xml file, but I still don't know what causes the problem in the first place.